# Close Dropdown Submenu After Click in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a website with bootstrap 3 framwork. now problem is, dropdown submenu not closed after clicking the sub-menu item. my templates uses hover function to show up sub-menu items. 
I want to close the dropdown when the user clicks sub menu item.

For an example, services menu contains submenu list. when the users clicks anyone of item, entire sub-menu should be closed. how to do? any suggestions?
[sitelink](http://demo1.thepartners.co.in/index.html)

Comment: this function should be triggered when click the sub menu

Comment: function() {
   $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
 }

Comment: $( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
  $(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
  $("#menulink + .dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");
});

This works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery( ".dropdown-menu li a" ).click(function() {
  jQuery("ul.dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: this is the function used for hover.

Comment: $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
 }, function() {
   $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
 });

Comment: function hidmenu() {
  jQuery("ul.dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");
}
add onclick="hidmenu()" in your menu

Answer (score 0):

Use display block in the css code

```
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra class to select the menu items which have dropdown element. For this example, a class "trigger" is used for defining which have child elements.

```js
$(function(){
 $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
  var current=$(this).next();
  var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
  if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
   $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
  grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
  grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
  current.toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
 $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
  var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
  root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
  root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
 });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu>li
{ position:relative;
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
 -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
 /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -1px;
 border-top-left-radius:0;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0;
 border-left-color:#fff;
 box-shadow:none;
}
.right-caret:after,.left-caret:after
 { content:"";
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
 margin-left:5px;
}
.right-caret:after
{ border-left: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
.left-caret:after
{ border-right: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Here <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
   <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 1</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
    <li>
     <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 2</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
      <li>
       <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 3</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this jquery

```
$( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
  $(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
  $("#menulink + .dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");
});
```

remove the open class of dropdown when a link is clicked

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kuladeep. it not works due to hover function.

Comment: can you share your code on fiddle so that i can help

Comment: try adding this line
$("#menulink + .dropdown-menu").css("display", "none");

or use the updated code in the answer